What's wrong when I try to derive the dual formulation of a convex problem with a norm constraint?
I have an optimization problem ($y$ is a vector):
\begin{align}
\min_y \quad c^Ty\\
s.t. \quad \Vert y \Vert \le \kappa\\
1^Ty=0\\
y\le b
\end{align}
which satisfies Slater's condition (the first inequality is active at $y=0$ while the third is an affine inequality), so the strong duality holds
I try to derive the dual problem with the dual variable being $\gamma, \alpha, \beta$ respectively.
\begin{align}
\max_{\gamma \ge 0, \beta\ge 0,\alpha} \quad \min_y \gamma\Vert y\Vert + (c+\alpha*\mathbf{1} +\beta)^T y -\kappa\gamma -b^T\beta
\end{align}
if $\gamma =0,c+\alpha*\bf{1} +\beta=0$
if $\gamma > 0, \Vert c+\alpha*\bf{1}+\beta \Vert_* \le \gamma$, or inner minimization can be $-\infty$
and the final dual problem is:
\begin{align}
\max_{\gamma,\alpha,\beta} \quad -\kappa \gamma - b^T\beta\\
s.t. \quad \Vert c+\alpha*\bf{1}+\beta \Vert_* \le \gamma\\
\beta\ge0\\
\end{align}
but I try run this simple problem with python and clearly these two are not equal. Could you please tell me which step is wrong? Thanks a lot!!

Presumably you have $b \ge 0$?

yes, and it is a vector, $y_i≤b_i$

Your formulation is correct as far as I can tell.

Maybe the problem is in the Python program? Can you post your counter-example?
